# How should I handle static assets when deploying code to different webservers?

Tags: deployment, cdn

Say I have two production webservers (`web1` and `web2`) and a static asset origin server (`origin1`), and I want to deploy new code that references new css/js/images.

After updating `web1` and putting it back on rotation, and right before I take `web2` out of rotation, there'll be a brief window when the load balancer will send requests to both `web1` with new code and `web2` with old code:

- `web1` serves html that requests `http://somecdn/images/foo.jpg?v=newhash`
- `web2` serves html that requests `http://somecdn/images/foo.jpg?v=oldhash`

So in this brief window, there's a chance that `somecdn` might request for `foo.jpg?v=oldhash`, but actually gets served the new image that just got deployed to `origin1`. That's not good.

The obvious solution seems to be keeping both versions of the assets available:

1. Version the releases like `/2.1/images/foo.jpg` and `/2.2/images/foo.jpg`, which defeats the purpose of cache-busting  using the file hash, or
2. Keep both versions by adding the hash to the file name, eg. keep both `/images/foo.oldhash.jpg` and `/images/foo.newhash.jpg` in the file system, which would leave a bunch of old files that needs pruning.
3. Setup Varnish to keep older versions of css/js/images around (feels iffy).

Is there a better strategy, assuming that I can't disable the site completely while deploying?

(StackExchange uses this file hash approach for cache-busting…)

Answer (score 1):

You basically have to keep both versions available during the transition if you are going to overlap versions in production at all. Using the versions in the path component is actually what we do, since it so much simpler for the devs. Approach #2 requires a lot more scripting work as part of your build/deploy process - just one more thing to break. We use hardlinks in the underlying filesystems to keep same files from /V1/ and /V2/ from taking up too much space, and it also makes pruning very easy. Our origins can handle the increased hits during changeover (which happen at low-usage periods anyway).